# Función con una lista de números

Tags: python-3.x

Diseña una función llamada importe_facturas que reciba una lista con los datos de las facturas de los clientes y un cliente y devuelva el importe total de las facturas de dicho cliente.

Los datos de cada uno de los clientes de la lista son:
- Nombre del cliente
- Importe factura

```py
def importe_facturas (L):
    importes = len (L)
    i = 0

    total_importes = 0 

    while i < importes:
        factura = L[i]
        resultado = int (factura[factura.find(" ") +3 : len (factura)])
        total_importes = resultado + total_importes

        i = i + 1

    return total_importes

L = ['Amazon 100' , 'Repsol 200' , 'Amazon 500', 'Lidl 500' ]
total_importes = importe_facturas(L, "Amazon") 
total_importes
```

Mi problema en este ejercicio es que al ejecutarlo me pone el siguiente error: 
TypeError: importe_facturas() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

El caso es que no sé como podría filtrar en la función el hecho de que cuando ponga el nombre de la  empresa en el paréntesis, me devuelva la suma de los importes.

Answer (score 0):

La funcion que creaste recibe como argumento la lista 'L', pero al ejecutar la funcion le agregaste (L, 'amazon')
Osea que le estas dando dos argumentos cuando a la funcion la creaste para que utilize un solo argumento. Por eso te tira ese error.

Comment: Ya ya, lo entiendo. Y sabría como podría agregar algo a la función para que tambien detectara el tipo de empesa?

Comment: Es en lo que no paro de fallar y

Comment: Pienso que en general la funcion no esta errada totalmente, si no que te falta agregarle el argumento donde reciba el nombre del cliente que deseas buscar, entonces al ponerlo en una variable, usarla para comparar la lista y poder asi sumar las facturas.

Comment: Si si, está claro que hay que añadir una variable. El tema es que no sé como puedo añadirla o como puedo ejecutarlo para que no me de error